# Weird cpu-load pattern

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, deepin

I am facing a strange (and rather annoying) problem with my laptop

**set-up**:
dual boot "Windows 10" and "Linux Deepin 14.2 (based on ubuntu)"

**problem**:
starting up with linux at the beginning everything is fine (cpu-load-wise):

[image]
After a couple of minutes of light work or idling things start to become weird and soon after a strange pattern stabilizes

[image]

of course this problem is very annoying:

1. Laptop is loud
2. Battery life is reduced dramatically (when compared to windows)
3. Laptop gets very hot

What I can exclude:

1. physical damage/dirtyfans since under windows the cpus stay at ~0% load when idling
2. Chrome is not the problem, the exact same thing happens even when I don't start any applications at all.

Any idea whats happening?

Comment: any  process show up in `ps -ef` or `top` ?

Comment: seems like the culprit process is initctl, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at what is running? Most desktops ship a process monitor but failing that, `htop` even `top` in the command line will show you what is *currently* using CPU.

If you have a case where it stops using CPU every time you look at it, you can log output over time with `pidstat`. Run `pidstat -u 600` and leave your laptop to idle for 10 minutes . When you come back you should have output of everything that has run, including how much CPU it used in that time.

Then it's just a case of working out why that process is going mental.

Comment: when I type top, the top line looks suspect:
 1045 root      20   0  133920 119692    876 R  99.7  1.5  67:21.56 initctl